# Bash: How to split a string into an iterable series of strings, on "\n"?

Tags: bash

If i have a string, which is as follows:
`` :x: **Line 1**\n`Line 2` ``

How can I split it into 2 strings (in this case) delimited by "\n", so that I can iterate through it as follows:

```
for LINE in $STRING
do
   echo "Line: $LINE"
done


Line: :x: **Line 1**
Line: `Line 2`
```

All the other examples i've tried from here, don't seem to do that, they only print the whole string out in one go.

For example, i've tried this:

```
STRING=":x: **Line 1**\n\`Line 2\`"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "Line: $line"
done <<< "$STRING"
```

and I get:

```
Line: :x: **Line 1**\n`Line 2`
```

Comment: What is output of `declare -p STRING` command

Comment: @anubhava declare -- STRING=":x: **Line 1**\\n\`Line 2\`"

Comment: Try this: `while IFS= read -r line; do     echo "Line: $line"; done <<< "${s//\\n/$'\n'}"`

Comment: You may be better off fixing how `STRING` is defined, so that it contains a real linefeed rather than the digraph `\n`.

Comment: @chepner Can't do that, I have to deal with what i'm given, which looks like it's a literal `\n` in this case (it's the raw text from a GitHub comment)

Comment: Is this pulled unparsed from a JSON value, then?

Comment: bit of a kludge ... replace the literal `\n` with a real linefeed: `sed 's/\\n/\n/g' <<< ${STRING}`; alternatively: `printf "${STRING}"`

Comment: @markp-fuso Can you show me that within the while loop please?

Comment: @markp-fuso, `printf '%b' "$STRING"` is safer -- doesn't try to recognize `%*` sequences but *only* handles backslash-escape sequences.

Comment: That's going to expand *all* escapes, though that may not be an issue. If this is a JSON fragment, it should be parsed with something that understands JSON, like `jq`.

Comment: @chepner, ...indeed, if something is using `\n`, I do expect `\t` and other escapes to be used and expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the literal `\n` into a linefeed and using in a `while` loop:

```
STRING=":x: **Line 1**\n\`Line 2\`"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "Line: $line"
done < <(sed 's/\\n/\n/g' <<< "${STRING}")
```

Or using the `printf` idea (including CharlesDuffy's comment):

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "Line: $line"
done < <(printf '%b\n' "${STRING}")
```

NOTE: Added the extra `\n` to make sure the 2nd line is terminated correctly so the `while` loop can read it.

Both of which should generate:

```
Line: :x: **Line 1**
Line: `Line 2`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "Line: $line"
done <<< "$STRING"
```

Comment: This does not work


    ````
    STRING=":x: **Line 1**\n\`Line 2\`"
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo "Line: $line"
    done <<< "$STRING"
    ```

    ````Line: :x: **Line 1**\n`Line 2`````

Comment: @JohnBergqvist: Your STRING doesn't contain a newline character; instead, it literally contains a backslash followed by a lowercase N. If you want it to contain a newline character, either change the double-quotes to dollar-sign-plus-single-quotes -- STRING=$':x: \*\*Line 1\*\*\n\`Line 2\`` -- or else use an actual newline character yourself -- STRING=":x: \*\*Line 1\*\*" on one line, \`Line 2\`" on the next.

Comment: Oh, that's a literal `\n`, not a newline, in the value?

Comment: @ruakh, How do i account for that if I can't change the input string? Or, how do switch on a literal "\n" then?

Comment: @JohnBergqvist, `printf -v string_literal %b "$string"`, and thereafter you can use `"$string_literal"` when you want real newlines instead of two-character `\n` sequences. (Note the use of lower-case variable names -- all-caps names are in space used by the shell itself and POSIX-specified utilities).

Comment: @JohnBergqvist, ...btw, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html for the relevant spec around variable naming (read keeping in mind that environment variables and regular shell variables share a single namespace, so to prevent your environment variables from being unintentionally overwritten you need to restrict shell variable names the same way).